# Partial downloads from Google Drive via Rest API take too long

Tags: c#, http, google-api, google-drive-api, postman

I am trying to download files from Google Drive and display a progress.

According to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads), the request for downloading a file from Google Drive accepts the `Range` header, but it does not make much of a difference. I am trying to download a `~40 MB` file and no matter whether I download chunks of `100 B`, `65 KiB` or `20 MiB`, each request will always take roundabout 30 seconds to finish, both on iOS and with Postman. The request for a smaller file with finish in `~300 ms`, hence it's not an issue with the access to the API per se.

The request I am sending with postman is

```
GET /drive/v3/files/<file id>?alt=media HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Range: bytes=0-100
Cache-Control: no-cache
Authorization: Bearer <My Token>
Postman-Token: ef19a353-98fe-4e7b-a892-a5a1a178d8a6
```

(The request from our app should be quite similar.) I would assume that it should return quickly, but it does not. It takes nearly as long as it would if I downloaded the whole (`~40 MB`) file.

Is there anything else I can do to receive partial downloads in a way that I can report a progress in a sensible way? Each chunk taking the same time the whole download would take renders the range header a bit useless.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks for your comment. IMHO it's not really debugging help, since it seems as if it not really my code, but the API, but I am trying to be more specific.

Comment: @DaImTo I've added the `GET`-request I am sending with postman, along with my expectations and how they deviate from the actual outcoming. Would you consider the changes appropriate, or is is still lacking crucial details?

Comment: So your not using googles official .net client library?    And this is a postman issue?  Making it not a C# issue so i am wondering why you have tagged it C#?